# User unable to access Repos

Tags: security, azure-devops

We have an issue.  User is in the Contributors group of the VSTS project.  Able to view dashboard and work items.  Unable to view Repos.  Need help.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you already looked at the repository security for the contributors group for the one you think they should be able to access?  You are sure they are not in any groups that would have the Deny permission on that Repo?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops#set-git-repository-permissions

Comment: Do they have at least a Basic license, or are they Stakeholders?

Answer (score 1):

User needed an MSDN license to use Visual Studio in addition to being in the correct group of the VSTS project.  Trial license was not good enough.

Comment: This guy is right, the user you add must have access to MSDN

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, highly doubt those users only have *Stakeholder* access level.

People with **Stakeholder**  access level could not commit their work on branch and unable to view repos.

> Assign Stakeholder access to those users who need to **enter bugs,
>   view backlogs, boards, charts, and dashboards,** but who don't buy basic access. Stakeholders can also view releases and manage release
>   approvals. Stakeholder access is free.
>
> *Source Link: [About access levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/access-levels)*

[image]

See [Stakeholder access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/get-started-stakeholder) for details of features available to stakeholders.

The user should have either **Basic access** or **Visual Studio subscription** which include **code**  feature.

---

Moreover, if it's still not able to see any other projects after giving them those access. There is another concept called **[Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions#nbspnbspnbsptfvc-object-level)**  in Azure DevOps. Double check the permission for Contributor group.

Also make sure you have not add them to any other project team group expect the contribute group.

Once deny the **Read** permission for repos level, user will not be able to see the repos.

> ***Read***
>
> Can read the contents of a file or folder. If a user has Read
>   permissions for a folder, the user can see the contents of the folder
>   and the properties of the files in it, even if the user does not have
>   permission to open the files.